# Minimizing the "distance" between a finite set of elements in a finite length sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization

Given a set of "options", $\{A,B,C,C\}$, I'd like to construct a certain kind of sequence of these elements.

And example sequence would be:

$ABCDABCD$

I define some average "distance" for this sequence that is calculated as the average distance between each specific element and it's nearest occurrence. To calculate that on the example sequence, we move along the sequence, starting at $A$. We seek the number of spaces before an $A$ appears again. That is $3$. We do this for $B$ as well, the answer is again $3$, as it is for all the elements. From this, we can arrive at the "average distance" for the sequence, $D=(3+3+3+3)/4=3$.

Now, I want to find a sequence that has the following properties: this average distance is minimized, all of the elements appear in the sequence the same number of times, the average distance for any given element should be the same as the average for the sequence. The length of the sequence is only constrained to be finite.

An example of a sequence with the same average distance is:

$AABBCCDDAABBCCDD$

Here, the average distance for any of the elements is $(0+6)/2=3$.

Is there a way to reduce this average distance?

Comment: Problem is not fully defined. Do you need to construct a sequence of a certain length? Also I'm assuming you HAVE to use all the 'options'? If so I suspect the answer is simply the number of options available. Not sure how to prove such a sequence is minimal though. Will think on this.

Comment: @wonko: I wasn't quite sure how to phrase the problem. It was just an interesting problem I thought of.

Comment: @wonko: Also, about sequence length - I was thinking that as long as it's finite, it should be fine. About using all options - yes, all the options should appear the SAME numbers of times in the sequence.